# Clickin on Information link brings up blank page

Tags: opencart

None of my Information links work, when I click on them it only shows up as a blank page. the URL is right and the ID numbers are right eg. ?route=information/information&information_id=4.
Strangely when I click on the Terms and conditions link when completing an order it takes me to the correct page but only shows the content and none of the formatting of the home page. If I click on the same link from the footer it just shows as blank.
I have activated logging and no errors appear, I have checked the footer.tpl and everything looks fine. Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The blank page is definitely an error, which should be visible in your error log (most likely from an extension/theme you've installed). If it doesn't show in the OpenCart error log under `SYSTEM > ERROR LOGS` then you need to check out your servers PHP error log. The T&C page is actually showing because it doesn't load through the same method as the one in your footer, and is supposed to be a simplistic page. However, this should load up in a popup not change your browser page. It sounds like your theme is screwing up